# TwoWay data binding between various controls

Tags: wpf

I'm very new to WPF, (I started yesterday) and I'm very confused about data binding. I have a View Model for a Window, which contains a widget called Foo which has its own View Model.

The widget Foo binds its Visibility TwoWay (via a BooleanToVisibilityConverter) to a bool field Visible on its FooViewModel. FooViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fires a PropertyChanged event whenever Visible is set.

In the Xaml for the Window, it creates a Foo whenever a button is clicked. The Window's view model has another boolean field which is bound TwoWay to the Visibility of its instance of a Foo View. The view model of the WIndow implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fires PropertyChanged events whenever the boolean field is modified.

What I expect this to do is whenever the window's boolean property changes, the visibility of the Foo instance will be set. When this happens I expect the View Model of Foo to be updated, since Foo's visibility binding is two way. When the Foo View Model changes its boolean field I expect the View to change its visibility. Further, I expect the Window view model to be notified that its instance of Foo is no longer visible, and hence the View model of the Window will update its own boolean field. Is this a fundamental misunderstanding?

I post the (obfuscated) code below if it helps shed light on this misunderstanding. Thanks.

Window Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="XXX.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModel"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:XXX"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:AppViewModel x:Key="AppViewModel"/>
        <vm:TwoWayVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppViewModel}}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_Connection" Command="{Binding Authenticate}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_About" Command="{Binding ShowAbout}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Logout" Command="{Binding Logout}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Configuration" Command="{Binding Configuration}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Info" Command="{Binding ShowInfo}"/>
            </Menu>
            <StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="White"
                Padding="10"
                BorderThickness="0">
            <TextBlock Text="XXX"/>
        </Border>
        <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Panel.ZIndex="1000" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppViewModel}}">
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=Modal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Mode=OneWay}"
                Background="DarkGray"
                Opacity=".7" />
                <v:Configuration HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Visibility="{Binding Path=ConfigurationVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <v:Connect HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Visibility="{Binding Path=AuthenticateVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Window View Model

```
class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Import(typeof (IEventBus))] private IEventBus _bus;

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        Authenticate = new ForwardCommand(obj => ShowAuthenticationView(), obj => !AuthenticateVisible);
        Configuration = new ForwardCommand(obj => ShowConfigurationView(), obj => !ConfigurationVisible);
    }

    public bool Modal
    {
        get
        {
            return AuthenticateVisible || ConfigurationVisible;
        }
    }
    public ICommand Authenticate { get; set; }
    public bool AuthenticateVisible { get; set; }
    public ICommand ShowInfo { get; set; }
    public ICommand ShowAbout { get; set; }
    public ICommand Logout { get; set; }
    public ICommand Configuration { get; set; }
    public bool ConfigurationVisible { get; set; }

    private void ShowAuthenticationView()
    {
        AuthenticateVisible = !AuthenticateVisible;
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AuthenticateVisible"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Modal"));
        }
    }

    private void ShowConfigurationView()
    {
        ConfigurationVisible = !ConfigurationVisible;
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ConfigurationVisible"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Modal"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

UserControl Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXX.Connect"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ConnectViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <vm:TwoWayVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Width="280" 
            Height="173" 
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Background="White">
        <Label Content="URL" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,12,0,0" Name="url" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" Text="{Binding Path=Url, Mode=OneWayToSource}" TabIndex="0" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,70,0,0" Name="username" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" Text="{Binding Path=Username, Mode=OneWayToSource}" TabIndex="2" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,41,0,0" Name="password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" Text="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=OneWayToSource}" TabIndex="1" />
        <Label Content="Username" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,39,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="Password" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,68,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="13">
            <Button Content="OK" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="5" Name="ok" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}" TabIndex="3" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Name="cancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" TabIndex="4" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl View Model

```
internal class ConnectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Import(typeof (IEventBus))] private IEventBus _bus;

    public ConnectViewModel()
    {
        ConnectCommand = new ForwardCommand(obj => Fire(),
                                            obj =>
                                            Visible && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Url) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Url) &&
                                            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Url));
        CloseCommand = new ForwardCommand(obj => Hide(), obj => Visible);
    }

    public ICommand ConnectCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    private bool _visible;

    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set { _visible = value; }
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        _bus.Publish<SessionCreatedEvent, SessionEventHandler>(new SessionCreatedEvent(Url, Username, Password));
        Hide();
    }

    private void Hide()
    {
        Visible = false;
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visible")); 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)...

Comment: Thanks H.B. I have taken note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding always works on properties. So while you Raise Visible in your Hide method, you don't raise it in the actual property. But the property is what the binding engine will set. If you bind this to another dependency property it won't get notified about it.
Btw. whats a TwoWayVisibilityConverter? [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) is perfectly capable of handling two way bindings.

tl;dr to make two way binding work properly (and in fact even one way binding) you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged **properly** which means, if the setter is called raise the property.

```
public bool Visible
{
    get { return _visible; }
    set 
    { 
        _visible = value; 
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visible")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm moving it back to BooleanToVisibilityConverter, I was under the misapprehension that it would only work one way. Would you suggest that moving the raising of the PropertyChanged event to the body of the setter is the problem here? Is there anything, in principle, wrong with expecting information to be passed from View Model to View Model the way I have attempted?

Comment: I have to say i had difficulties getting your code. But this seems to me the most obvious problem with it. There are rare occasions where you don't want to raise in the setter, but in another method. But usually raising in the setter is the best way. If you don't raise it, the setter is called but your view can't know it. There is no magic in data binding, wpf listenes to the PropertyChanged event and calls via reflection the getter of the raised property to update the value. if you don't raise it, wpf doesn't know it.

Comment: Respectfully, I'm not really asking the question so you can show me how to move a statement into a property setter - it's more that I don;t understand the framework. I don't understand why I need to fire the event in the setter. If I set a value at t0 and fire an event at t1, then I would expect the framework to receive my event, get the value of my property and retrieve the value I set at t0. Is this assumption incorrect? If it is not incorrect, then I surely do not need to fire the event until the command executes, if I want to delay notification. Is there more to it than this? Thanks.

Comment: Like i said you don't have too. You can fire the event whenever you feel the need. But from my understanding of your problem is, that there are occasions where your code is not called by you. And this happens in TwoWay binding scenarios. If now WPF calls your setter because of a twoway binding, and there is no property rais, but another binding is listening to changes, it can't know of the Chance and won't do anything until you raise it manually. If thats not the problem nor the case, then my apologies and you can ignore my answer.